# $n$ piles, $m$ objects. Choose two piles and remove n objects in total from the two piles. Iterate. For which (m,n) is it possible to empty all piles.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

Let $m < n$ be positive integers. Start with $n$ piles, each of $m$ objects. Repeatedly carry out the following operation: choose two piles and remove $n$ objects in total from the two piles. For which $(m,n)$ is it possible to empty all the piles?

I think it is the case that for $k$, natural number, $(k,2k), (ak, ak+a)$ works.

Observation: $m\ge n/2$.

Non-trivial solvable case: $(m,n)=(9,12)$

The first solution is trivial. I proved the second one by induction.

> Are there any other solutions and is the second solution correct?

Comment: So you are obligated to take at least $1$ object from each of the two piles, right?

Comment: Yes. Since n>m.

Comment: Not following the rules.  Say there are $10$ piles, each with $2$ objects.  That corresponds to $(m,n)=(2,10)$, right?  But how could I hope to remove $10$ objects from two piles?  And if I can just empty those two piles, and then move on to the others...well, where's the obstruction to emptying all the piles?  Or did you mean for use to assume that $2m≥n$?

Comment: Yes, correct. That’s the point. The question is you need to find for which m,n it works (i.e. end up with none left). Something you should note is that m=>n/2

Comment: I suggest adding this to your post...it's not something one would guess easily.  Also:  why not add an explicit example of a non-trivial solvable case?

Comment: Done. If you read the problem, and look at a few cases, it is something that one could easily see within 2mn. I also added the example, which can be derived from my formulae

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $(9, 12) $ is non-trivial?

Comment: Note that $(b, 2b) $ is  a subcase of $(ak, ak+a)$, like with $ a = b, k = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the set of pairs $(m,n)$ such that $n>m$ and $n-m\mid m$. First, let $m=(n-m)k$, where k is a positive integer. It can be rewritten as $m(k+1)=nk$. Since $k$ and $k+1$ are always coprime, $k\mid m$ and $k+1 \mid n$. If we denote gcd$(m,n)$ by $a$, we get the answer in your form $(ak, ak+a)$.

Now let us prove that all such pairs work. We have $k+1 \mid n$, so we divide all the piles in groups of $k+1$. Each group can be processed as follows: we take the first pile ($m$ objects) and $1/k$-th part of the last pile in the group (remember that $k\mid m$), then the second pile and again the part of the last pile, and so on.

Finally, let us prove that $n-m\mid m$ is a necessary condition. Assume that at some step we took $k$ objects from a pile, where $n-m \not\mid k$. What did we take from the second pile? $n-k$ objects. Since there are $m$ objects in any pile, the fate of the other $m-(n-k)=k-(n-m)$ is still unknown. Note that $k-(n-m) \not\mid k$. All these objects were taken at some point, perhaps in several steps. But there was such a step when we took the number of objects from these $k-(n-m)$ which is not divisible by $n-m$. We can repeat this reasoning and every time the number of objects will get smaller but would never be divisible by $n-m$. So it can’t get to $0$ which it should.

Therefore, number of the objects we take from a pile is divisible by $n-m$, and so is the number of the objects in the whole pile. We are done.